# graficando con chartjs -ajax - php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, chart.js

hola amig@s tengo un problema que al generarse las graficas haciendo evento change de un select en vez de reiniciarse se sobrepone una grafica sobre la otra y al pasar el mouse sobre ella a veces muestra los resultados anteriores o los actuales
Codigo php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css"> 
    <title>DATATABLES</title>
    <script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <script src="Chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section class="principal">
    <h1>BUSQUEDA DE JUGADORES</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.writeln(e);
</script>
    <div class="formulario">
        <label for="caja_busqueda">Buscar</label>
        <select type="button" name="caja_busqueda" id="caja_busqueda"  value="gonzalez acosta"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>        
    </div>
    <div id="datos"></div>
    <div id="canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 200px">
        <canvas id="mybarChart"></canvas>
    </div>  
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Codigo js - para consultar

```
$(buscar_datos());
function buscar_datos(consulta){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'buscar.php' ,
        type: 'POST' ,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {consulta: consulta},
    })
    .done(function(respuesta){
        $("#datos").html(respuesta);
         e = respuesta;

        var ctx = document.getElementById("mybarChart");
              var mybarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                  labels: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Jjulio"],
                  datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    backgroundColor: "#26B99A",
                    data: [e, 30, 40, 28, 92, 50, 45]
                  }, {
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    backgroundColor: "#03586A",
                    data: [41, 56, 25, 48, 72, 34, 12]
                  }]
                },

                options: {
                  scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                      ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                      }
                    }]
                  }
                }
              });

    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log("error");
    });
}


$(document).on('change','#caja_busqueda', function(){

    var valor = $(this).val();
    if (valor != "") {

        buscar_datos(valor);
    }else{
        buscar_datos();
    }

});
```

codigo php - este codigo lo que hace es consultar en la base de datos y enviar con la informacion al ajax.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "tienda";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Conexión fallida: ".$conn->connect_error);
      }
    $salida = "";
    $query = "SELECT sum(monto_venta)  as r from ventas where month(fecha_venta)= 1";
    if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
        $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
        $query = "SELECT sum(monto_venta)  as r from ventas where month(fecha_venta) = '$q' ";
    }

    $resultado = $conn->query($query);

    if ($resultado->num_rows>0) {


        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            $salida.=$fila['r'];

        }

    }else{
        $salida.="NO HAY DATOS :(";
    }


    echo $salida;

    $conn->close();



?>
```

la base de datos lleva como nombre : tienda

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.5
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1:3306
-- Tiempo de generación: 07-02-2020 a las 13:17:21
-- Versión del servidor: 5.7.26
-- Versión de PHP: 7.2.18

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `tienda`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `ventas`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ventas`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ventas` (
  `id_venta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_venta` date NOT NULL,
  `monto_venta` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `ventas`
--

INSERT INTO `ventas` (`id_venta`, `fecha_venta`, `monto_venta`) VALUES
(1, '2014-01-15', 15000),
(2, '2014-02-13', 10000),
(3, '2014-03-11', 12000),
(4, '2014-04-22', 13000),
(5, '2014-05-22', 30000),
(6, '2014-06-14', 11500),
(7, '2014-07-30', 10200),
(8, '2014-08-16', 15000),
(9, '2014-09-23', 10000),
(10, '2014-10-02', 12000),
(11, '2014-11-20', 13000),
(12, '2015-01-20', 30000),
(13, '2015-03-11', 11500),
(14, '2014-11-20', 10200),
(15, '2015-01-20', 9500);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

agradezco me puedan brindar su ayuda o en su defecto enviarme otro tema relacionado para con Dashboard mensuales

Comment: Has probado limpiando el canvas antes de llamar a la función buscar_datos() ?

Comment: Si amigo lo intente con empty pero no me vuelve a generar gráfica después de hacer el change en el SELECT

Comment: encontre esta solucion, comparto por si les sirve

Comment: document.getElementById("canvas").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("canvas").innerHTML = "<canvas id=\"mybarChart\"></canvas>";